# Beginning Hibernate 3.5 - Problems with ant task

Tags: java, hibernate, ant, slf4j

I'm trying to work through "Beginning Hibernate 3.5", and I've hit an initial snag.

When I run `ant exportDDL`, I get the following error:

```
exportDDL:
   [htools] Executing Hibernate Tool with a Hibernate Annotation/EJB3 Configuration
   [htools] 1. task: hbm2ddl (Generates database schema)
   [htools] SLF4J: The requested version 1.6 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.5.5, 1.5.6, 1.5.7, 1.5.8]
   [htools] SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#version_mismatch for further details.
   [htools] An exception occurred while running exporter #2:hbm2ddl (Generates database schema)
   [htools] To get the full stack trace run ant with -verbose
   [htools] Problems in creating a AnnotationConfiguration. Have you remembered to add it to the classpath ?
   [htools] java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.format(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/slf4j/helpers/FormattingTuple;

BUILD FAILED
C:\hibernate\project\build.xml:30: Problems in creating a AnnotationConfiguration. Have you
remembered to add it to the classpath ?
```

with the following ant task:

```
<target name="exportDDL" depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${sql}"/>
    <htools destdir="${sql}">
        <classpath refid="classpath.tools"/>
        <annotationconfiguration
                configurationfile="${src}/hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
        <hbm2ddl drop="true" outputfilename="sample.sql"/>
    </htools>
</target>
<target name="compile">
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${bin}" classpathref="classpath.base"/>
</target>
```

What's going on here? `ant compile` works fine, but the `exportDDL` task does not. The sl4j jar is on the classpath, and I downloaded `slf4j-simple-1.6.1.jar`. Thoughts?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here solves what you want

> **Mixing mixing different versions of slf4j artifacts can cause problems**. For example, if you are using slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar, then you should also use slf4j-simple-1.6.1.jar, using slf4j-simple-1.5.5.jar will not work.
>
> **In general, you should make sure that the slf4j-api version matches that of the slf4j binding**.
>
> At initialization time, if SLF4J suspects that there may be a version mismatch problem, it will emit a warning about the suspected mismatch. For the exact details of the version mismatch detection mechanism, please refer to the relevant entry in the FAQ.

Comment: Yup. Looks like sl4j-api-1.5.8

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example I came across of the SLF4J start up warning when you've got incompatible slf4j versions:

SLF4J: The requested version 1.5.10 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.6]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#version_mismatch for further details.